# Trying to pull JSON data via the crunchbase API. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Result</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>   
    <script>


     $(document).ready(function() {
     $.getJSON("http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/facebook.js?api_key=mgxpds8ja7f6cncwd39caed7")
      });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I feel like there is something ridiculously easy  I'm missing, but I can't seem to pull any data off.

Comment: On the contrary, it doesn't look like you're doing anything with it.

Comment: You are fetching the values, but what are you planning to do with the fetched values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I see a couple of things..

1. Include the Jquery script tag.
2. Add an id to the place you want to put the results.
3. Change the script like mentioned below..
4. Check the settings with the API Key and or Simply use your php backend to retrieve the JSON and then put it un your page. Using JSON like that will return a cross-domain error.

Check the HTML below, works like a charm, but for the x-domain error...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Result</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="results"></div>   
    <script>


     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#results").html( function () {
     return $getJSON("http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/facebook.js?api_key=mgxpds8ja7f6cncwd39caed7")
});      
});

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

@leo.

Comment: Once I changed the callback problem this worked fine. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 3):

There is same origin policy violation in the code, you need to do pass an additional parameter `callback=?` so that it will make use of [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to make the request.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/facebook.js?api_key=mgxpds8ja7f6cncwd39caed7&callback=?", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    //Do something with the data
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UqkGu/)

Answer (score 0):

After fetching JSON, for next step you need to add callback and do some action with JSON data,

```
$.getJSON("http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/facebook.js?api_key=mgxpds8ja7f6cncwd39caed7", function(data){
       //CALLBACK
       console.log(data); //LIST DATAs
       //Do Something over here
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/